# How to write an expression in report builder to separate first and last name?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I have a column with a full first name and last names. Some with middle initial, and some are even company names. I'm looking for some code to extract first and last name only.

For first name i'm using

```
=Left(Fields!Name.Value,Instr(Fields!Name.Value," "))
```

And last name i'm currently using

```
=Right(Fields!Name.Value,Len(Fields!Name.Value)-Instr(Fields!Name.Value," "))
```

I'm thinking I can create an if statement to count the length of the column. if 3 and under, grab the last string for last name? (first, middle, last)

If more than 3 then use full name as name could be 'A & B Dashing Company'

using report builder 3.0, kind of new at this stuff.

Comment: Take a look at the answer posted here.  It may or may not help you.  If anything it can point you in the right direction. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539988/sql-cross-apply-to-split-names-into-first-last-and-mi/55541412#55541412

Comment: You might need to modify your table to include something like a bit column. 0 for individual, 1 for a company. I could see a lot of problems coming from trying to force something in SSRS. What if the company is `The Company` and you're trying to split it based on how many words?  I would recommend adding a column to your dataset. Will save you trouble in the future.